# Google Sheets, formula based conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

Can custom formula based conditional formatting use NamedRanges ?

I'm experiencing that when named range is used, I cannot save the conditional formatting because formula is invalid, but when the NamedRange is replaced by a string it works. The docs do not allude to details, AFAIK.

```
ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("ArrivalTimes!$A$4:$S$653")) // OK
ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(RNG_ArrTimes))               // now allowed to save
```

Is this expected behaviour? Any docs available on this?

EDIT; based on answer for reader convenience.

AS suggested by @pnuts, it works when the range name is within double quotation marks.

However, while INDIRECT expects a string, in Sheets INDIRECT accepts NamedRanges as is without quotation marks. But, for conditional formatting, the named range must be within quotation marks. I have not found any docs that document or explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Can custom formula based conditional formatting use NamedRanges ?

Indeed they can.

The rest of your Q is unclear to me but perhaps it is just that you are missing double quotes around the Name of your range (and `=` at the beginning?).

[image: From the documentation]

Comment: Putting double quotes around the range_name works. Have to say its odd because the range_name does not require quotes in normal sheet formulae. I had expected that the same visibility (of named ranges) would apply in the same manner.